# Given the equation $y=3\left(\dfrac12\right)^{-x}+3$

Tags: functions

a) state the base function.
b) Describe the transformations

I know that the base function always has to be positive, but what would the base function be if the exponent is $-x$?

Also, for the transformation, I know that it moves vertically up $3$ units but what are the other transformations?

Comment: $(\frac{1}{2})^{-x}=2^{x}$

Comment: would the base function not be 3 instead of 2

Comment: Is *base function* same as *basis function*?

Comment: I am not sure the question just states to find the base function of the given equatioln

Comment: I suspect what is meant by the base function is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$.  You then have to consider the effects of negating the $x$, multiplying by $3$, and adding $3$.